# convert PH-MySQL Application into setup files which includes MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php-mysql application, which is running through WAMP server on my local machine. I want to run that in my client's computer. It can be made by installing wamp server manually in my clients computer but i want to create a setup file which will install the wamp server as well as import all the database which the application is using and provide easy interface for the client to access and use the application. How to do ????

How it can be done by Inno setup which include the database too?

Comment: Have you performed into research or made in efforts in trying to achieve this task?  What specific part of this task are you having problems with?

Comment: i found that it can be done by a software called exeoutput and Inno setup but in the both case they are not including my "mysql" DATABASE